# how to manage a queue?

Tags: c#, queue

firstly sorry for my English, hope you understand.
I have a timer which update a 'object[][] tempServices' per 1 Sn  and sends to below function
what i want to do is adding elements of tempServices to the queue, but only one time (no equal elements at queue).

```
 myQ = new Queue<object[]>();



public void AddToQueue(object[][] tempServices)
        {
            bool checkQueue;
            lock (myQ)
            {
                foreach (object[] tSer in tempServices)
                {
                    checkQueue = false;
                    if (myQ.Count == 0)
                        myQ.Enqueue(tSer);
                    for (int i = 0; i < myQ.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cv = myQ.ToArray();
                        if (tSer == myQ.ElementAt(i))
                        {
                            checkQueue = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            checkQueue = true;

                    }
                    if (checkQueue)
                        myQ.Enqueue(tSer);

                }
            }
        }
```

this code works fine for first time but other times still keeps adding from tempServices to queue again and again. lofts of same elements, I want only add different elements
for example
(don't look at type of example)

tempServices___queue

1-2-3 ***_*_**_1-2-3

1-2-3-4_**__**_1-2-3-4

2-4-6_***_*_**_1-2-3-4-6

7_***_*__*_***_1-2-3-4-6-7

Whats problem at this code?
thanks..

Comment: Your title is very clear.. Please unclarify it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Do you really need to remove items from the queue in the order they came in?

Comment: no, it is not about order. what i mean is add only one time each elements in the queue no repereated elements in the queue. and i figured out my code works fine when the func AddToQueue calling in a loop, but when it is calling from a timer it is not working right. adding every time is the timer working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Queue<T>.Contains` Method to check whether an item already exists in the Queue and return 'true' if it has similar item or else 'false'. This will give the freedom to choose whether or not to enqueue items to your queue. Keep in mind that, this method determines equality using the default equality comparer `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` for `T`, the type of values in the queue. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hb6387f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link for sample code.

Comment: I cahnged my code to using .Contains method but stil same problem, and when call the function from a loop again and again 2 version of codes work fine(each element of queue only one time) but when i call from a timer writes every time, as if .contain method not working right.

Comment: If your 'tempServices' is custom data structure like custom class then you must provide a custom implementation of IEqalityComparer<T> where T is your custom class. As a side note, you non of these are the cause then its wise to see your code as I think there might be some bug in your code.

Comment: tempServices's type is object[][] and T is same(object[][]).

Comment: What is the type, which your are likely to have it within object[] array ? Is that int,string or custom types ?

Comment: string. but is it can be about types?? I'm confused. code works fine in a loop only problem using in timer. in timer contain method always returne false

Comment: Let me reiterate (a) You can skip adding same element to Queue using Contains method. (b) try to reduce the frequency in which your timer run the code (3) try to lock on a static object rather than queue object. Ie. private static object lc =new object() and use 'lc' within you lock construct.